# How do I change behaviour of eshell/rm (rm in eshell) tab completion?

Tags: completion, eshell, builtin

**Qestion**:
Is there a way to make eshell/rm (especially) either display a completion buffer even for few files or remove the . and .. entries for eshell/rm.

**Background** (and some ranting):

So I learned the hard way that in `eshell/ls` and `eshell/rm` tab completes differently.
While eshell/ls has the behavior I expect(sortof) eshell/rm has a rater "disturbing" querk...

lets say you have `~/Download/this_dir/somefile.txt`

You go to `$ ls ~/Download/this_dir/` and tab complete `ls` will complete to the file. 
However, if you do the same with `rm` it will cycle through the following outputs

```
$ rm ~/Download/this_dir/somefile.txt
$ rm ~/Download/this_dir/./
$ rm ~/Download/this_dir/../
```

notice the last entry points to the parent directory (ouch). 
I (may be to my own fault) if I expect only one file in this directory press tab a number of times just to make sure I am at the top which made me cycle to the parent directory entry, which is hard to see if the filepath/name is long and hit enter.

**Additional Investigation**

I realized that the TAB key is bound to pcomplete which is discussed [here](https://masteringemacs.org/article/pcomplete-context-sensitive-completion-emacs) but I haven't found the exact thing to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following analysis/example applies to *nix operating systems:

`eshell/rm` and `eshell/ls` are `elisp` implementations of `rm` and `ls`.  They do *not* control the functionality of completions within `eshell`.

The function `pcomplete/rm` within `pcmpl-unix.el` uses `pcomplete-all-entries` instead of `pcomplete-entries`.  The difference is that the former let-binds as `nil` the variables `pcomplete-file-ignore` and `pcomplete-dir-ignore`.

If the user loads the module `em-cmpl`, then `pcomplete-file-ignore` is set *locally* to the value of `eshell-cmpl-file-ignore` and `pcomplete-dir-ignore` is set *locally* to the value of `eshell-cmpl-dir-ignore`.

Because the original poster has not specified whether the library/module `em-cmpl` has been loaded, the following example simply hard-codes the value for `pcomplete-file-ignore` and `pcomplete-dir-ignore`.  As alluded to above, we want to be able to take advantage of the variables to ignore files and directores -- so we use `pcomplete-entries` *instead of* `pcomplete-all-entries`.

```lisp
(require 'pcmpl-unix)

(defun pcomplete/rm ()
  "Completion for `rm'."
  (let* (
      (pcomplete-file-ignore nil)
      (pcomplete-dir-ignore "^../$\\|^./$")
      (pcomplete-help "(fileutils)rm invocation"))
    (pcomplete-opt "dfirRv")
    (while (pcomplete-here (pcomplete-entries) nil 'expand-file-name))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm on a *nix system and also just verified that `em-cmpl` library loads when I run `M-x eshell`. I will look in to the variables you suggested and see if I need to redefine `pcomplete/rm`

Comment: You should look at `pcomplete-all-entries` to see how it binds `pcomplete-file-ignore` to `nil` and `pcomplete-dir-ignore` to `nil`.  If you continue to permit `pcomplete/rm` to use `pcomplete-all-entries` *instead of* `pcomplete-entries`, then changing the value of the variables will *never* have the intended effect.  The *name* of the function at issue strongly hints at its intended purpose -- i.e. **all** of the entries.